# How can I mix and map sound channels in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, windows-8, audio

The built-in windows mixer, which can be accessed through Volume Control, allows users to change the output volumes of individual applications. I would like something similar but with additional functionality.

I want to be able to control the output levels for each output speaker. For example, if I had a 5.1 channel device connected and correctly configured in Windows, I would like to be able to mute the front and centre speakers.

I also want to be able to remap the output sound channels to different physical speakers. For example, I would like to remap the front left and right speakers to the rear ones.

I would like to know if there is any generic Windows software or configuration that I can use to do this. I want a generic solution that is not specific to any particular sound card or output devices, and it should work on at least Windows Vista.

Answer (score -1):

[here is a software](http://profound-sound-csharp-win7-32.en.softonic.com/) i used to control/amp/sycn sounds of my external speakers, 7.1 custom made, Profound sound has everything you want, give it a spin,

Comment: The link you provided triggered my Adblocker for spam. I would advise against posting such links on Stack Exchange

Answer (score -1):

`Realtek HD Audio Manager` which works for Realtek sound cards will do the "Room Correction" (per speaker leveling) but it won't do the remapping